# Need help understanding this variable inside a function

Tags: javascript

This is pretty basic stuff but I'm trying to wrap my head around this to continue my understanding of basic Javascript syntax.

Basically, I don't understand why the variable `length =  queue.length;` is created. 
Why can't the for loop just loop `i < queue.length` rather than making a variable for it.

```
var puzzlers = [
    function ( a ) { return 8*a - 10; }, 
    function ( a ) { return (a-3) * (a-3) * (a-3); }, 
    function ( a ) { return a * a + 4; },
    function ( a ) { return a % 5; }
];
var start = 2;
var applyAndEmpty = function( input, queue ) {
   var length = queue.length;
   for(var i = 0; i<length; i++){
       input = queue.shift()(input);
   }
   return input;
};
alert(applyAndEmpty(2, puzzlers));
```

Comment: FWIW, I’d use `while (queue.length)`…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that inside the loop, you've got:

```
queue.shift()
```

The [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) method removes the first element from the array and returns it. That means that the `queue` is constantly resizing, but your `i` variable is increasing regardless. If you didn't have that, it would actually iterate through the first only half the elements in the queue.

Comment: Ok I see now, I had to really think about it and then test it without it to see what would happen. I have a feeling a lot of little things are going to fly right past me. These little things are a bit frustrating for me lol.

Comment: Wow, I just looked at this again without the length variable and just the queue.length in the loop and I feel so liberated. The shift() method removes the first array from the queue which means the i++ is still adding a value to i and that's why it's finishing at the second array. I know you're not supposed to thank people in comments but man, thank you! This was bugging me for the past hour lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it! But you'll have a big sentence. You could use just `queue.length` instead of using a variable.

Answer (score -1):

Because the "queue.length" will do property lookup and this is very expansive, so saved it in local variable to make the loop in good performance. 
please see more in this link:http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html#javascript_code_execution_with_timers?

Comment: As p.s.w.g points out, this isn’t why, and the “very expansive” [sic] is just wrong. Don’t micro-optimize!